# Create array from nested array with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

Is it possible to create array like that:

```
Array
        (
            [Name] => John
            [Last Name] => Doe
            [Age] => 19
        )
```

from nested array like that:

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => John
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Last name] => Doe 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Age] => 19
        )
```

Nested array is created when adding values in array while making a loop

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
        $users[] = array($user['title'] => $user['value']);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to alter the final array or the part where the array is build?

Comment: I need final array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More simplified @NigelRen's solution is using `array_column`:

```
$output = array_column($users, 'value', 'title');
```

Comment: It's too early in the morning for me to come up with this, but yes it is a better answer!

Comment: I don't understand how I miss this :+1|

Answer (score 4):

You should change the way the array is built rather than process it further.  You are currently adding new arrays each time...

```
$output = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $output[$user['title']] = $user['value'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly that I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_walk_recursive` it will also work if you have nested array

```
array_walk_recursive($a, function($v, $k) use (&$new){ $new[$k]=$v;});
```

DEMO :- https://3v4l.org/UGQou

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$result = array_reduce(array(
    array("Name"=>"John"),
    array("Last Name" => "Doe"),
    array("Age" => 19)
),function($a,$b){return array_merge($a,$b);},[]);
print_r($result);
```